# How to Reference a Global Variable within another Global Variable in extensions.conf?

Tags: configuration-files, asterisk

In `extensions.conf`, can I reference one global variable within another?

```
[globals]
GROUP1=SIP/3333&SIP/3334&SIP/3335
GROUP2=SIP/4442&SIP/4441&SIP/4442
GROUP3=SIP/5553&SIP/5550&SIP/5556
```

Like this?

```
EMERGENCY=${GROUP1}&${GROUP2}&${GROUP3}|9999|30
```

If not, how can I do the equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is completely doable.  As arheops mentioned, the values for the variables are substituted when an expression is evaluated in RTL order.

Example dialplan:

```
[general]

[globals]

TEST1=SIP/111&SIP/222
TEST2=SIP/333&SIP/444
TEST_GROUP=${TEST1}&${TEST2}

[default]

exten => 1,1,NoOp()
    same => n,NoOp(${TEST1})
    same => n,NoOp(${TEST2})
    same => n,NoOp(${TEST_GROUP})
    same => n,Dial(${TEST_GROUP})
    same => n,Hangup()

exten => 2,1,NoOp()
    same => n,Wait(5)
    same => n,Hangup()
```

Example execution using a fresh checkout from Asterisk 1.8, showing the variable values:

```
*CLI> channel originate Local/1@default extension 2@default
    -- Executing [1@default:1] NoOp("Local/1@default-505e;2", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [1@default:2] NoOp("Local/1@default-505e;2", "SIP/111&SIP/222") in new stack
    -- Executing [1@default:3] NoOp("Local/1@default-505e;2", "SIP/333&SIP/444") in new stack
    -- Executing [1@default:4] NoOp("Local/1@default-505e;2", "SIP/111&SIP/222&SIP/333&SIP/444") in new stack
    -- Executing [1@default:5] Dial("Local/1@default-505e;2", "SIP/111&SIP/222&SIP/333&SIP/444") in new stack
```

Comment: Matt Jordan, you are my friend!  I wish I could write you an email!  You got my vote.  Can I do that in Asterisk 1.2, as well (until I get switched over)?

Comment: Hmmm... How can arheops be right to say ${} substitution won't work in the config, and yet in this example here, it looks like it does, indeed work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible in 1.2, but I would expect that it would work.  The fundamentals of how Asterisk interprets dialplan variables haven't changed drastically over the years.  As far as what arheops was talking about, I'm honestly not sure.  While 'the dialplan' can be expressed in .conf file format (and most typically is), comparing it to other .conf files that act as a source of configuration information is really comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Just create enother logic or external script to do create dialplan file

Comment: Is that the case even for Asterisk 1.8?

Comment: i think yes. reason is simple. ${} is substitution.it not work in config file at all.